# jQuery selector passes undefined for populated input field

Tags: jquery-selectors

This js script select the value of inputfield with name: id_add_to_cart and pass to ParseProductId that parse the value:

```
$("input[id='add-extra']").live("click",function () {
    var product_id = $("input[name='id_add_to_cart']").value;
    parseProductId(product_id);
    return false;
});
```

The parsed value is undefined for this HTML:

```
                    <form action="" method="POST">';
                        <input type="hidden" name="id_add_to_cart" value="100" />
                        <input type="submit" id="add-extra" value="Add" />';

                    </form>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[id='add-extra']").live("click",function() {
    var product_id = $("input[name='id_add_to_cart']").val();
    alert(product_id);
});
```

change `.value` to `.val()`.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/egiwor/2

Answer (score 0):

```
var product_id = $("input[name='id_add_to_cart']").val();
```

Does this change anything?